# Relationship between positive definite matrix eigenvalues and the principal axes lengths of ellipsoid

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In many textbooks of pattern recognition I have seen the following statement:

**If a matrix $A$ in the quadratic form $F(\text{x}) = \text{x}^{T}A\text{x}$ is positive definite, then it follows that the surfaces of constant $F(\text{x})$ are hyperellipsoids, with principal axes having lengths proportional to $\lambda_{k}^{-1/2}$.**

$A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix, $\lambda_k$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, $\text{x}$ is a non-zero vector and $k = 1, ..., n$.

My question is: "Why are the principal axes of hyperellipsoids proportional to the eigenvalues of $A$? Why are they proportional to $\lambda_{k}^{-1/2}$? And why are the  surfaces of constant $F(\text{x})$  hyperellipsoids?"

Can someone give me a proof? Visualization perhaps? etc. Anything that would make me see that this indeed is the case :)

Hope my question is clear :) 
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $A \in \def\R{\mathbb R}\R^{n\times n}$ is positive definite, there is an orthogonal $Q \in O(n)$ (that is a matrix whose columns form an orthonormal basis of $\R^{n}$) such that $QAQ^t = \mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n) =: \Lambda$ with the $\lambda_k$ positive. For $c > 0$ and $x \in \R^n$ we have 
\begin{align*}
  F(x) &= c\\
 \iff x^t Ax &= c \\
  \iff x^t Q^t QAQ^t Qx &= c\\
  \iff (Qx)^t \Lambda Qx &= c\\
  \iff \sum_k \lambda_k (Qx)_k^2 &= c\\
  \iff \sum_k \frac{(Qx)_k^2}{(c^{1/2}\lambda_k^{-1/2})^2} &= 1
\end{align*}
So in the transformed coordinates $y = Qx$ given by $Q$ we see that the hypersurface $\{F = c\}$ is given by 
$$
  \frac{y_1^2}{(c^{1/2}\lambda_1^{-1/2})^2} + \cdots + \frac{y_n^2}{(c^{1/2}\lambda_n^{-1/2})^2} = 1 
$$
that is it forms a hyperellipsoid with principal axes in direction $Qe_k$ (where $e_k$ denotes the $k$-th standard unit vecotr) having lengths $c^{1/2}\lambda_k^{-1/2}$.