Explain how geometric axes of an ellipsoid corresponds with eigenvectors and eigenvalues

What is the algebraic/geometric definition of principal axes when we refer to ellipsoids?

How do we start from this definition of principal axes then argue that the eigenvectors/eigenvalues give the directions/lengths of the principal axes?


There was a post linked below deriving the relationship:
$\frac{y_1^2}{(c^{1/2}\lambda_1^{-1/2})^2} + \cdots + \frac{y_n^2}{(c^{1/2}\lambda_n^{-1/2})^2} = 1$
It is not sufficient. My question is why we can interpret the various numbers as principal axes and length. For example, how do we relate a geometric definition of principal axis to this equation? Wikipedia says a principal axis is some axis defining an axis of symmetry for an ellipsoid. So, for example, starting from the geometric definition of axis of symmetry / principal axis and moving towards the above equation, is what I'm looking for.

Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449342/relationship-between-positive-definite-matrix-eigenvalues-and-the-principal-axes?rq=1

@A.ThomasYerger It does not. I updated my question.

I think the main thing that bridges the gap is that ellipsoids, being homogenous equations of degree 2, represent quadratic forms. The symmetry then naturally tells you that the axes of the ellipsoid are eigenvalues.

What’s the definition of principal axis of an ellipsoid?

They're the line segments cut out by the symmetries of the ellipsoid.

Yes, but I am looking for an explicit connection from a geometric definition of principal axis to the algebraic definition of principal axis given by the equation. Perhaps your earlier comment goes into this but it's not verbose enough for me to understand
